# Why they have different size? (next/image & img html element)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

Different sizes!
[image]
The image by `next/img` component and the image by `img` element have different sizes.
They use same image source, and have same style!
But `next/image` make the image shrink, `img` element does not.

- image by `next/img`
  [image]
- image by `img` element
  [image]

code:

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="flex">
      <Image src={appleImage} alt="apple" priority />
      <Image src="/apple.png" width={600} height={840} alt="apple" />
      <img src="/apple.png" alt="apple" />
      <img src="/apple.png" width={600} height={840} alt="apple" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

*className `flex` is for tailwind.css

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
}
```

I want to know why they have different sizes.

Comment: I do not know next.js but I checked their doc and see you might have to set an ```layout="fill/fixed/etc.."```. See more here https://refine.dev/blog/using-next-image/#width-and-height . You could give that a try. This changes the behavior of what the width and height element do.

Comment: May be <Image /> is has some css applied with the image component.  So please inspect element with CSS

Comment: @Dakshank I've already checked the inspector. but they have the same style!
(only difference is a property of inline style `color: transparent;`. and I've inactivated that, but nothing changed)

and the `<Image>` doesn't have a wrapper component. It just returns `<img>`.

Comment: Hi, I've tried to reproduce the problem in my application but I'm getting exact same images from both `Image` and `img`. Can you add a sandbox with your code?

Comment: I think it happens because of the 'srcset'. `next/image` automatically makes the 'srcset' from one source. it makes this difference. maybe...

Comment: @AnushkaChauhan I've tried to reproduce on the sandbox but failed. I think the 'tailwindcss' also affects it. They become the same when I remove the tailwindcss in my project. but they are still rendered in different way, which you can check on the devtool.

Comment: @AnushkaChauhan Try adding css `height: auto` for `img`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you can see there are three images in your code the next js provides image efficiency that decreases the size according to width and they make them responsive. In your case, you have one image from HTML that is taking the full 600 pixels but due to the screen surface not being available for 1800 px  3*600 the next images are shrunk automatically but now their aspect ratio gets disturbed you can add a property `height: auto` in your CSS file and aspect ratio also becomes good if you want to use exact size then you need to do `width: 600px !important`